# Zero score for accessibility because of contrast ratio

Tags: seo, accessibility

This [URL](https://www.codiwan.com/ldap-installation-tutorial-openldap-ubuntu/) got a zero score for the Accessibility audit section.

Here is the the [Lighthouse Report](https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com//lh/html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codiwan.com%2Fldap-installation-tutorial-openldap-ubuntu%2F#accessibility)

[image]

I wanted to know how find the locations at which this check failed because I cannot find a way to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: I have trouble with the red text on the gray terminal background (symbols) and the dark yellow text on the same background (comments).   Try a different theme for the syntax highlighting and see if you can find one that has better contrast for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with CSS `overflow` properties. Seems overflow property can hinder Lighthouse's ability to run Accessibility audit.

Reference: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11721

I saved your page as HTML on my local machine. When I tried the lighthouse audit for the page, I encountered the same error. I then created a copy of the page with all `overflow` properties removed from the source. Lighthouse was able to measure Accessibility now.

[image: overflow removed page]

**Note**: The report for the new page also shows the specific elements where you have to improve the contrast ratio.

Comment: Hi @Kannan - Thanks for the answer. I didn't find any element/css with `overflow-x` attribute.

Comment: The page contains overflow properties in inline style. Please check the source. And, sorry, I removed overflow properties and not overflow-x.

Comment: And one more point: A question mark in accessibility (in your screenshot) denotes an error and not a zero score.

Comment: You were correct, the code blocks were very which made the experience poor. I've shortened the width of the code lines.